# how to restrict an additional admin user access to a specific category in magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

i have **added an additional admin user and created a role** for it, allowing access to **manage categories and products** and it **works fine**.

But what **i want is to limit his/her access to a specific category products only**  .i.e.

he will be able to manage products of only specific category.

Any help on that will be appreciated.

*********** edited ***********************

Actually the idea is of Vendor that is vendor can manage his own category only, his own products, can see orders and invoices of only his products etc.

Do inform me if there is any existing module/extension for this.

Comment: or atleast limit additional user to add products only, will not be able to delet products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-vendor-dropshipping-extension.html) which satisfies my requirements but is too costly, **i wish i could have developed it by my own.**

:-?

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension from aitoc called "Advanced Permissions"
With this you can restrict the access to categories etc. Here you can find the feature list:
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: i guess it was build before at the time of magento version 1.3, but the later versions include these module by default.
Am i right ?

Comment: to limit the access to special categories you need an extension. Without you can only deny/allow the access to the whole catalog.